# Sql Db Query wild Character

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to delete all entries with column containing digits in `BirthRule`. (One Highlighted in bold). what wild character i should use

Column:

BirthRule
**Birth1Rule

Birth2Rule

Birth3Rule**

Comment: Oracle provides regular expression support. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Comment: Can you please tell me which wild character will i use here

Comment: I strongly suggest you do your own research. Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1007267.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you *select* them; convert it to *delete* for exercise.

```
SQL> With test (col) as
  2  (select 'birthrule'    from dual union
  3   select 'birth2rule'   from dual union
  4   select 'birth100rule' from dual union
  5   select 'drhouse'      from dual union
  6   select 'dr13crandall' from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9  from test
 10  where regexp_like(col, '^birth\d+rule$');

COL
------------
birth100rule
birth2rule

SQL>
```